# Avoid conflicts in jQuery library for more than 2 library

Tags: jquery

How can I avoid jquery conflict for more then two libraries.
Currently I have 3 plugins but I'm not able to avoid conflict.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("input[id$='firstName']").keyup(function(){
    alert("first Name");
  });   
});

var jq171 = jQuery.noConflict(true);   
jq171.ready(function($) {
  jq171(".tel-mask").mask("(999) 999-9999");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id$=firstName]').rules("add", {
    required: true,
  });  
});
```

Comment: seems like ow you are doing noConflict is wrong....

Comment: declare like this
`var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
// $j is now an alias to the jQuery function; creating the new alias is optional.`
now use `$j` instead of  `$` everywhere.

Comment: I'm still facing same issue

Comment: The best way to avoid conflicts is to not use multiple versions of jQuery. Are you 100% absolutely, positively sure there is no updated version of the libraries you use? Or alternatives that support modern versions of jQuery? Using `$.noConflict` for multiple jQuery instances should be a last resort. Also, given the code you've shown above there's no reason you need multiple versions at all

Comment: I'm not using muliple versions of jQuery, I'm using different libararies

Comment: Which ones are you using?

Comment: Different libraries has nothing to do with noConflict mode in jQuery. noConflcit is when you are using another library that is also using the `$`. It is not going to fix issues when two scripts do not work together when applied to the same element. What is the exact issue you are having and what libraries have the conflict? What is the conflict?

Comment: I'm using jQuery Validator, MaskedInput, and jQuery